# Fastest way to loop through Map keys

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, dictionary, key

Let's say I have a map with the keys:

```js
const map = new Map([['a', 'Apple'], ['b', 'Banana']])
```

I want to loop through the **keys** of the map (`'a'`, `'b'`).

I know these ways of looping through the keys:

### `Map.prototype.forEach()`

```js
map.forEach((_value, key) => {
    console.log(key)
})
```

Pros: Simple

Cons: Have to ignore first param in function - `(_value, key) =>` instead of just `key =>` .

### Create array from `Map.prototype.keys()` and then `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```js
[...map.keys()].forEach(key => {
    console.log(key)
})
```

Pros: Callback can just be `key =>`

Cons: `[...map.keys()]`. Might be confusing when reading the code and might be less performant.

### `for of` loop through `Map.prototype[Symbol.iterator]()`

```js
for (const [key] of map) console.log(key)
```

Pros: Probably fast. Easy to read.

Cons: Not an arrow function (opinion that forEach is better).

### `for of` loop through `Map.prototype.keys()`

```js
for (const key of map.keys()) console.log(key)
```

Very similar to previous method.

So I want to know which way is the most performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSBench](https://jsbench.me/4flj9ovm2j/1) with the methods as per the following. These are the results from fastest to slowest:

1. `Map.prototype.forEach()`
2. `for of` loop through `Map.prototype.keys()`
3. `for of` loop through `Map.prototype[Symbol.iterator]()`
4. Create array from `Map.prototype.keys()` and then `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Comment: note that with iterating over values its sorta the opposite: for of fastest https://jsbench.me/xnl0ws0kfm/1

Comment: @ColinD Your jsbench is titled "Fastest way to loop through Map key" but I think you meant to say "value"

Comment: @programmerRaj I took a look at your JSBench, and saw you are using console.log inside of the test loops. That isn't very reliable for performance testing. If you change the console.log lines to another simple operation (like a value assignment) you get very different results.

Comment: improved JSBench: https://jsbench.me/4flj9ovm2j/1

Answer (score 2):

There is one more which seems to be the fastest:

```
for (let [key, value] of  map.entries()) {
    sum+=value
}
```